# Ember data error: model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this model, that throws an error when I navigate to this route with this router and model. It is the register one causing the issue.

register Route model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  newUser: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The register route I am using for this model:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find("account-type");
  }
});
```

here is my router:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('register');
  this.route('my-account');
  this.route('change-password');

  this.route('app', function () {
    this.resource('profile', {path: 'profile/profile_id'});
    this.route('connections');
    this.resource('conversation', {path: 'conversation/conversation_id'});
  });

  this.resource('myAccount', function() {});
  this.route('user');
});
```

user model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  surname: DS.attr('string'),
  dateOfBirth: DS.attr('string'),
  telephoneNumber: DS.attr('string'),
  accountType: DS.belongsTo('accountType'),
  emailAddress: DS.attr('string'),

  //used to present full-name
  fullName: function () {
    return this.get('title') + ' ' +
      this.get('firstName') + ' ' +
      this.get('surname');
  }.property("title", "firstName", "surname")

});
```

the error I'm getting :

```
model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name
```

Here is the stacktrace I'm getting:

```
Error while processing route: register Invalid fullName: `model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name`  TypeError: Invalid fullName: `model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name` 
    at __exports__.default.EmberObject.extend.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16812:17)
    at Object.resolve [as resolver] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16434:25)
    at resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14970:32)
    at Object.Container.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14550:16)
    at factoryFor (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15053:31)
    at Object.Container.lookupFactory (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14657:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.modelFactoryFor (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73164:31)
    at ember$data$lib$serializers$json_serializer$$default.extend.extractArray (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67267:22)
    at apply (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32891:27)
    at superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32459:15)
```

I wonder if it has to do with my mock?

apprev:

```
  accountTypesRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(
       ["foo", "boo"]

      /*
          [
       {"id": 1, "type": "foo"},
       {"id": 2, "type": "baa"}
       ]
      * */

    );
  });
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the full stack trace for the error? Also please tell us which versions of Ember and Ember-Data you're using.

Comment: @GJK maybe its because my route model is empty, I don't populate it on the route

Comment: Sorry, just so I know what I'm looking at, which versions of Ember and Ember-Data are you using? The versions should be printed in your console when you run your app.

Comment: @GJK "ember": "1.8.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.14.1",

Comment: The stack trace says there's an error while transitioning to your `register` route. Can you post that route and your router please?

Comment: Honestly, I can't see anything wrong based on what you've posted. My best guess is that you have an `@each` where there should be a type name. Do you use `@each` at all in your code?

Comment: not an @each in my code

Comment: If you're not using `@each` at all, this is possibly a bug (or at the very least, a poor error message). Unfortunately, I think the only way to help may be for you to reproduce your error in a JSBin or JSFiddle. Can you try doing that? Also, try upgrading to Ember 1.10.0 if you can.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper are you using a real server or mocking the server response for `this.store.find("account-type");`?

Comment: Why back your register route with a model at all? Do you want to keep a registration around for some reason?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper it seems like it's getting caught up with your `fullName` computed attribute. Try removing that to see if it's related to the problem.

Comment: maybe its my mock as shown:

Comment: @JamieChong I'm also getting warnings like this:  WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("0"))

Comment: If I comment out the fullName prop I still get the same error..

Comment: time to throw this into jsbin

Comment: @KalmanHazins ohh.... this may take ages..

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys I have a model because this route will send a register model to the server. I populate this route with a default user and password which will be sent back.. am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @MarcioJunior atm I'm just using the mock    ["foo", "boo"], for live I will use parse.com to get this back via the parse-rest-adaptor

Comment: here is a great starting point - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mipuwa/1/edit?html,js,output for putting this into jsbin...

Comment: @KalmanHazins thanks, do my mocks have to return id's?

Comment: Your mocks should return whatever payload your real server would/does return

Comment: What does the accountType Model look like? You mocks should be returning something like `{accountTypes: [{id:1, type:'foo'},{id:2, type:'boo'}]}` If the real API doesn't return that, write a DS.RestSerializer.

Comment: @KalmanHazins I think something is wrong with the broc cache, I will try clear it/start a fresh cli project. I deleted the prop fullName and it still shows the error. weird

Comment: @JamieChong my mock server returns [{id:1, type:'foo'},{id:2, type:'boo'}] fine :)

Comment: @SuperUberDuper but I'm pretty sure that the array has to be wrapped in an object keyed with `accountTypes` - as I've shown in my previous comment.

Comment: @JamieChong yeah your right, please put it in an answer. Why does ember require it to be wrapped?

Comment: A good primer on how Ember Data expects your json response to look: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API needs to return the JSON data formatted in a certain way. Ember wants an object that is keyed with the name of the Model. So like this:

```
{
    accountTypes: [{
        id: 1, 
        type: 'foo'
    },{
        id: 2, 
        type: 'boo'
    }]
}
```

If you can't control what is returned from the API endpoint, write a [DS.RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) to transpose the JSON into something that Ember Data wants. For example if your server payload looks like this:

`[{id:1, type:'foo'},{id:2, type:'boo'}]`

You can write a serializer like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend( {
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        payload = {
            'accountTypes': payload
        };
        return this._super(store, type, payload);       
    },
});
```

As @Kori pointed out, the [DS.RESTAdapter docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_object-root) briefly discusses the JSON format Ember Data expects.